# Header and Footer repeating in end of the word document

Tags: visualforce, css, header

any one help me on this, it's urgent. Header and footer are displaying end of the word document. I am using landscape as page size. If I change page size landscape to any other it's working fine. But I need to show the document with landscape, because I have to display data in large no. of columns. How can I remove the repeated header & footer in end of the document?

**CSS:**

```
<head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">           
            @page main {
                size:11in 8.5in;
                mso-page-orientation:landscape;
                mso-header:header1;
                mso-footer:footer1;
                margin-top:80px;
                margin-bottom:80px;  
                margin-right:20px;
                margin-left:20px;
                mso-paper-source:0;
            }
            div.main {
                page:main;
            }
            p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter {
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
            }
            p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader {
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
            }
            table#hrdftrtbl{
                margin:0in 0in 0in 9in;
            } 
        </style>
    </head>
```

**header & Footer:**

```
<table id='hrdftrtbl' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--Header-->
            <div style='mso-element:header' id="header1" >
                <p class="MsoHeader">
                    <table border="0" width= "100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-bottom:1px solid #736D6E">
                         <tr>
                             <td width="3%" align="left" height="30%"></td>
                             ------------------
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                </p>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <!--Footer-->
            <div style='mso-element:footer' id="footer1">
                <p class="MsoFooter">
                    <table style="border-top: 1px solid black;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     <tr>
                         <td width="3%" align="left" height="30%"></td>
                             ------------------
                     </tr>
                 </table>
                </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got solution for this after lot of struggling. I did small modification in css.
That is:
table#hrdftrtbl{
                margin:0in 0in 0in 15in;
            }